# Why services configured with NSSM output error messages to the standard output

Tags: stdout, stderr, nssm

Recently I configured two separate services with the Help of NSSM.
For both, the **stdout** and the **stderr** are being output in the **stdout** file and thus **stderr** file is always empty even if there are error messages.

The services themselves are working as expected.

They have been initially configured via CLI with the following commands:

```
nssm install servicename "C:\service\path\file.exe"
nssm set servicename AppDirectory "C:\service\path"

nssm set servicename AppStdout "C:\service\logs\stdout.log"
nssm set servicename AppStderr "C:\service\logs\stderr.log"

nssm set servicename AppStdoutCreationDisposition 4
nssm set servicename AppStderrCreationDisposition 4

nssm set servicename AppRotateFiles 1
nssm set servicename AppRotateOnline 1
nssm set servicename AppRotateSeconds 0
nssm set servicename AppRotateBytes 50000

nssm set servicename Start SERVICE_AUTO_START
nssm start servicename
```

Openning the NSSM GUI shows that everything is configured as expected.

This seems to be some kind of a bug within NSSM. Is there a solution to it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you figured it out?

Comment: unfortunately, not. I'm just looking for errors in the stdout file :)

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a solution to your problem, but in my case the problem was coming from that the service was logging to the stdout only instead of separating the output stream to stdout and stderr. Maybe worth checking this.

For me NSSM is logging correctly to stdout and stderr now.